# t-test or Wilcoxon test in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I have a very small data sets of web traffic to compare the effect of performing advertising over five days or seven days. Yes, running a test over 7 days would definitely give me more traffic but I would like to know if the traffic is significantly higher and worth my consideration.

I run each test for 2 weeks.

This is my dataset:

```
5day advertising web traffic    7day advertising web traffic
week1   week2                     week1    week2
184418  179650                    301978    308019
```

I ran the t-test in R and got this value

```
> a<-c(184418,179650)
> b<-c(301978,308019)
> t.test(a,b)

t = -31.9557, df = 1.898, p-value = 0.001307
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -140407.5 -105521.5
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 182034.0  304998.5
```

Is my dataset too small and does this mean that there is a significance difference?

When I run the Wilcoxon test (via `wilcox.test`), I get a different output:

```
data:  a and b
W = 0, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Are these four different weeks? Btw. something is wrong with the numbers (mean of y is higher than its two measurements)

Comment: I'm guessing something went wrong with your inputs to the t-test; the `mean of y` at the bottom of your second code block should be 199355.5, not 304998.5.  That's quite apart from the fact that your sample size is really too small to draw any conclusions, I'm afraid.

Comment: "Significantly higher" and "worth my consideration" are two different things.  The former assesses whether your conclusions might be caused by chance variation in the data, whereas the latter is a determination of the *value* or *cost* of the observed difference. By focusing on significance you might be getting a good answer to the wrong question altogether.

Comment: I edited my data for the 7 day test, it is actually much higher and I also put in the full code i used.The tests were ran over 4 consecutive weeks with the 5 day test in the first 2 weeks and the 7 day test in the next 2 weeks. Would looking at daily traffic be better than getting weekly aggregated data?

Comment: What are these numbers? Are they *counts* of something?

Comment: Hi @Gung, they are number of visits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you are trying to do, I am not sure a t-test is what you want.

I am guessing that advertising for 7 days costs more than advertising for 5. So, let's look at cost per day:

```
Week 1: 184,418/5 = 36,883 per day
        202,316/7 = 28,902 per day

Week 2: 179,650/5 = 35,930
        196,395/7 = 28,056
```

Then what impresses me is that the difference is nearly the same for the 2 weeks. The question of how to test this is, I think, not so important.

In fact, if 5 days is M-F and 7 is every day, you might consider trying only the weekend!

Of course, cost may not be the same per day, in which case the above would have to be modified.

Comment: Hi Peter, the data is for traffic and not spend

Comment: OK, but my point is the same - more traffic is good and traffic per day of advertising seems key, since more ads surely costs more money.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got when I used your data. I would go with the results of the wilcoxon test since your sample size is so small.

```
x1<- c(184418, 179650)
x2<- c(202316, 196395)

t.test(x1,x2)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -4.557, df = 1.913, p-value = 0.0488
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -34409.9541   -233.0459
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 182034.0  199355.5 

wilcox.test(x1,x2)

data:  x1 and x2
W = 0, p-value = 0.3333
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Under perfectly satisfied assumptions (normal distribution within groups, equal variances, independence), a t-test works even with group sizes of just 2. (Of course you can't check the conditions.) This is in contrast to a Wilcoxon rank-sum test that needs at least four observations per group to produce a p value below 0.05. Thus, a Wilcoxon test is of no use here I am afraid.